# Can we use the same signing key for two different android apps?

Tags: android, android-app-signing

Is is Ok to use a single signing key to sign two different application for release to Google PlayStore?

Is there any problem with that? Is there any gotchas? Is it a good or a bad practice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At least the two applications can not be installed on the same device.

Comment: @AIMINPAN Its 2 different package with same key, its still can installed on same device

Comment: yes, its OK to use same key for all of your application

Comment: Sorry my ignorance. Good to know this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone !! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can use as many App you want to release using the same signing key only your package name should be different across all release.

> Is there any problems?

Actually No.

> Good or Bad practice?

I think you should create different signing key for your different Apps. Consider the scenario where you have multiple APKs with the same signing key. If, by chance, you lose your signing key, you won't be able to update any of your existing apps in the future. Therefore, keeping different signing keys for each app helps mitigate such risks and ensures better manageability and security.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was thinking too!! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Great answer. Another argument for signing your different apps with different signing keys is if you ever have to give/sell one of your apps, you would need to hand over the signing key of that app, and you wouldn't want the buyer to be able to also sign APKs of your other app.

Comment: another great reason :D